# TemplateView Vs ListView: different output

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Look, i am playing with the Django documentation through making their examples by my own.
I have come across with a behaviour giving different ouptuts just by changing very few portions of code:

WITH A LISTVIEW:

Views.py snippet:

```
class UsuarioListView(ListView):

model = Usuario

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UsuarioListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Urls.py:

```
  url(r'^listaUsuarios/',UsuarioListView.as_view(),name='listado_usuarios'),
```

Giving as result when visiting:

> Usuarios

```
luis
paco
sonia
```

It is correctly listing the 3 users i have,
BUT! if i try to use the [TEMPLATE VIEW](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) based on the example from django

views.py:

```
class UsuarioListView(TemplateView):

template_name="listado_usuarios.html"

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UsuarioListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

(with from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView)

Urls.py:

```
 url(r'^listaUsuarios/',UsuarioListView.as_view(),name='listado_usuarios'),
```

Urls remains the same, and the output is:

> Usuarios

```
No hay usuarios.
```

(THERE ARE NO USERS)

So, how is that possible, one shows the 3 users i have and the other way none.
By the way even the template is correct, here it goes:

```
<h1>Usuarios</h1>
<ul>
{% for u in object_list %}
    <li>{{ u.nombre}}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No hay usuarios.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Sorry if this is a very silly question or if i forgot something here. Hope somebody can get me out of doubt...
Also, the "users" i am listing are corresponding to a model i create, not the django users table.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you are using a `ListView` with an assigned model, it will automaticaly generate an `object_list` based on your entries from that model.

On the other hand, if you are using a `TemplateView`, and you want to iterate through `object_list`, you'll have to generate it first, since the `TemplateView` won't do this.

If you go in your `TemplateView`, `get_context_data()` and do: `context['object_list'] = Usuario.objects.all()`

`ListView` generated an `object_list` with all the objects from the model you specify and sends it to context, while the `TemplateView` needs you do generate manualy the context data.